# Heroku Redis upgrade from free to paid stuck in "preparing (plan upgrade in progress)"

Tags: redis, heroku

I'm trying to upgrade Heroku Redis from the free hobby plan to a paid version but it seems eternally stuck in in "preparing (plan upgrade in progress)".

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: contacting their support?

Comment: Is that even an option? I looked around, but I just see Premium Support and a FAQ Environment.

Comment: Well, a community that has no relations to their services will not be able to help you.

Comment: There is an option to create a ticket with standard support: https://help.heroku.com/?t=true